# Removing Objects from an ArrayList

Tags: java, android

Hi I am a bit new to Java and Android. I am working on a project which it cycles through random Activities and I am stuck with a problem for days.

```
public class ActivityHelper extends Activity {
    ArrayList<String> classes = new ArrayList<String>();
    public   void addClass (){
        classes.add("Activity1");
        classes.add("Activity2");
        classes.add("Activity3");
                //etc

    }
    public  String openClass (){
        addClass();
        Random rand = new Random ();
        int crazy = rand.nextInt(classes.size());
        String cheese = classes.get(crazy);
        classes.remove(cheese);
        return cheese;  
    }   
}

// A Method in Activity1 extends ActivityHelper
public void doJob() {

    String cheese = openClass();
    try {               
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.activity.dan." + cheese);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Activity1.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The program perfectly cycles through the classes but my problem is the `classes.remove(cheese);` doesnt work. I am hoping once the Class is opened it will be removed from the ArrayList and wont be used again if the `doJob();` method is called on another class. I tried using static and putting the remove list in the `Activity1` but nothing seems to work. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: where do you call all these methods? what is your `onCreate()`?

Comment: use this `classes.remove(crazy)` instead of classes.remove(cheese) because remove method take an index of item see [sun java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `remove` is working but each `Activity` you create contains a new instance of `classes` and that's not what you want. It might work this way.

```
public class ActivityHelper extends Activity{
static ArrayList<String> classes = new ArrayList<String>();
static {
    classes.add("Activity1");
    classes.add("Activity2");
    classes.add("Activity3");
            //etc
}
public  String openClass (){
    // don't add classes here - would be done every time.
    // print out some debug
    Log.d("ActivityHelper", "State before openClass: " + Arrays.toString(classes.toArray()));
    Random rand = new Random ();
    int crazy = rand.nextInt(classes.size());
    String cheese = classes.get(crazy);
    classes.remove(crazy);
    // print out some debug
    Log.d("ActivityHelper", "State after openClass: " + Arrays.toString(classes.toArray()));
    return cheese;
}
```

Comment: Hi tried this method but still it seems to be creating a new Instance of the class. Also tried removing via index but still same case. I am hoping to work around it and try a ArrayList of Classes and randomly cycle through them if possible. Any thoughts?

Comment: if you print (e.g. `Log.d("TAG", Arrays.toString(classes.toArray()));`) the content of `classes` in `openClass` is the content really reset all the time? Because if `classes` is static then it will exist only once for all instances of your Activity. That will not work if your Activities are in different apps or processes though. And a restart of your app (kill with some TaskManager) might reset `classes` as well.

Comment: @danpasco I've added some debug to the Answer. It should print a list that always gets smaller. If not you might need to use e.g. `SharedPreferences` to keep a list of Activities you still want to be opened.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList.remove() expects an Integer, not a class.
Call .remove() with the Integer index you want to remove and it should work as expected.

Comment: remove() is overloaded. remove(int) and remove(Object)

Comment: @SergeyBenner: hi,can you give me an example where we pass an object in `ArrayList.remove(int index)` apart from Integer Object.

Comment: By bad, didn't see that it accepted Object as a parameter. Either wa try removing by index? Clearly not working for Object